# Could MimbleWimble increase privacy in the Monero network?

Tags: ringct, mimblewimble

MimbleWimble needs a very minimal scripting language which Monero has, but doesn't use, and also takes advantage of Monero's RingCT. Is there anyway mimblewimble could run on top of Monero or in a sidechain maybe? Also would it help with scaling in anyway? Or is mimblewimble just not really very helpful in Monero whatsoever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to answer such broad questions because answering it requires deep understanding of both technologies. But in general, throwing one thing on top of another doesn't necessarily make it better, especially if a desired feature is already present by some other means, as it is with Monero. Mimblewimble is interesting, but on its own.

It's a novel approach to a problem, but it doesn't feel like it could be compatible with what Monero is already doing in a diferent way. See [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/751/does-mimblewimble-have-any-relevance-to-new-pruning-ideas-for-monero) for some considerations.